# Pasting a .jpg into Illustrator CS6 renders it bigger than in CS4?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, jpg

I am pasting a jpeg from photoshop into Illustrator CS6, say 5 inches wide. When I used Illustraor CS4, it would come in at exactly the physical size you copied from PSD. Now it gets pasted in .ai CS6 huge. Then I have to reduce to fit my page. What's different?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the initial jpeg and the CS6 file resolution are both on inches.
The conversion done on Adobe's cut/paste between software usually works best on the same suite (within CS6 all around, etc.).